# Associative table not mapped - Hibernate + netbeans

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, netbeans, hql

My Tools :

- Netbeans 8.x
- Hibernate plugin
- PHP my admin

[image]

HQL Query :

```
SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM UserApp ua
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    ua.userId = 1
```

Error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Userapp is not mapped [SELECT a.applicaitonName
FROM Userapp ua
    LEFT JOIN Application a On ua.applicationId= a.applicationId
WHERE
    ua.userId = 1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
```

How I proceeded to do that:

- I created hibernate.cfg.xml
- I created hibernate.reveng.xml
- I created Hibernate Mapping Files and Pojors from database

When I create Hibernate Mapping Files and Pojors from database, it created 2 news objects : `Application` and `User`. But not `Userapp` ...

do I have to create it manually ?

[image]

Here the hibernate.reveng.xml (Something strange, UserApp is write in blanck and not in grey like User and Application :

[image]

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="allin"/>
  <table-filter match-name="user"/>
  <table-filter match-name="application"/>
  <table-filter match-name="userapp"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such mapping table normally don't get explicitly mapped by Hibernate but only implicitly by a ManyToMany mapping. Therefore your HQL statement should look somewhat like this

```
SELECT a.applicationName
FROM User u left join u.applications as a
WHERE u.userId = 1
```

I can't tell what the correct property name for applications is ... You'd should be able to look that up in the source code.

How to do this kind of joins in HQL is described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins